# firebase Analytics logEvent is not visible on Google Analytics, only android 13

Tags: firebase

I have try getting logEvent on Firebase Analytics but specifically it is not visible for Android 13. Is there any reason for that? How do I solve the problem?

I am not sure about the procedure to attempt but I expect to see the logEvent for Android 13.

Comment: Facing a drop in events with Android 13. @Panha did you find a way to fix this ?